# How to detect if a website can be embedded as iframe (SAMEORIGIN)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vue.js

What's a way to detect whether a website can be embedded or not because of the same-origin policy?

I have tried way to detect this but failed. I only found old method. But none of them work now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if same origin policy applies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404793/check-if-same-origin-policy-applies)

Comment: I have tried load, pass message event, setTimeout..etc. still not work..maybe there is some example or answer recently?